# How to dynamically create a struct column from a list of column names?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 100's of columns:

```
root
 |-- column1
 |-- column2
 |-- column3
 |-- column4
 |-- column5
```

I have a list of the column names:

struct_list = ['column4','column3','column2']

Expected Schema:

```
root
 |-- column1
 |-- column2
 |-- column3
 |-- column4
 |-- column5
 |-- prev_val 
       |-- column4
       |-- column3
       |-- column2
```

Currently I am hardcoding the values like:

```
df=df.withColumn("prev_val",f.struct(f.col("column4"),f.col("column3"),f.col("column2"))
```

Is there a way we can dynamically pass the values from the list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

struct_list = ['column4','column3','column2']

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "prev_val",
    f.struct(*[f.col(c) for c in struct_list])
)
```

And actually you don't even need `f.col`. You can just pass the column names directly:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    "prev_val",
    f.struct(*struct_list)
)
```