# How to create a struct column from a list of column names in Spark with Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-java

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns, e.g.

```
root
 |-- playerName
 |-- country
 |-- bowlingAvg
 |-- bowlingSR
 |-- wickets
 |-- battingAvg
 |-- battingSR
 |-- runs
```

I also have a list of the column names which corresponds to bowling stats:

List bowlingParams = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("bowlingAvg", "bowlingSR", "wickets"));

Expected Schema:

```
root
 |-- playerName
 |-- country
 |-- bowlingAvg
 |-- bowlingSR
 |-- wickets
 |-- battingAvg
 |-- battingSR
 |-- runs
 |-- bowlingStats 
       |-- bowlingAvg
       |-- bowlingSR
       |-- wickets
```

I can do it like this

```
playerDF = playerDF.withColumn("bowlingStats", functions.struct("bowlingAvg", "bowlingSR", "wickets"))
```

However, I want to use the list to dynamically select the column for struct.

I know we can do it like this in Scala

```
playerDF = playerDF.select(struct(bowlingParams.map(col): _*))
```

and, I have also found a reference on [how to do this in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022293/how-to-dynamically-create-a-struct-column-from-a-list-of-column-names#)

Is there a way we can do this in Java with Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For java this solution worked for me,

- remove the one attribute from list(non dynamic one)
- convert the remaining list to Scala Sequence using JavaConverters.
- when creating nested column , in struct use one attribute(as string) and your converted Scala Seq.

  ```
   import scala.collection.JavaConverters; 

   List bowlingParams = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("bowlingSR", "wickets"));


  playerDF = playerDF.withColumn("bowlingStats", functions.struct("bowlingAvg",JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(bowlingParams.iterator()).asScala().toSeq()));
  ```