# How to combine multiple column into one single json structure in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case where I want to combine multiple columns values into one single String column in spark?

```
Source

FirstName|LastName|Age
Anuj     | Rai    |26

Target

FirstName|LastName|Age | person_details
Anuj     | Rai    | 26 | {FirstName:"Anuj",LastName:"Rai",Age:"26"}
```

I saw that in scala we can do this by using struct but how to do the same in java.I did not find any struct method in java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72346244/1477418

Comment: In scala we'll write something like this: 
`df.withColumn("person_details", to_json(struct($"FirstName", $"LastName", $"Age")))`
Hope this can help you in order to write this in Java